# How to deal with build error from org.eclipse.pde.core

Tags: maven, tycho, eclipse-pde

Hi I am costantly getting this build error at my maven/tycho project from the plugin org.eclipse.pde.core, any idea how to deal with it?

```
Errors running builder 'Plug-in Manifest Builder' on project 'myProject'.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource.createMarker(java.lang.String, java.util.Map)'
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.builders.IncrementalErrorReporter.applyMarkers(IncrementalErrorReporter.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.builders.ErrorReporter.validateContent(ErrorReporter.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.builders.ManifestConsistencyChecker.validateFiles(ManifestConsistencyChecker.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.builders.ManifestConsistencyChecker.validateProject(ManifestConsistencyChecker.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.builders.ManifestConsistencyChecker.build(ManifestConsistencyChecker.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: What versions of Eclipse and Tycho are you running? That method was added in Eclipse 4.19 (2021-03)

Comment: Well try with the current Eclipse 2021-09 which has that method.